# Progress on Simon's 1984 problem of the proof of Universality

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, statistical-physics, ising-model

I am writing this post to inquire if any progress has been made in solving problem 8B (Proof of Universality) proposed by Barry Simon in [1984](http://math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/R27.pdf).

The problem goes like this:

> Show that the critical exponents in the three-dimensional Ising models with nearest neighbor coupling but different bond strengths in the three directions are independent of the ratios of these bond strengths.

Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update from 2004 is given by Yurishchev in [Universality in the partially anisotropic three-dimensional Ising lattice.](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0410629)
When the lattice anisotropy parameter is varied by three orders of magnitude, the numerically estimated thermal and magnetic critical exponents change only by a few per cent, in accord with the universality hypothesis.

No progress has been made on a mathematically rigorous calculation. Such progress is expected to be as challenging as an exact solution of the 3D Ising model, which has been elusive.